# How do you use CSS to absolutely place objects partially off the screen without vertical scroll bars?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a container object with height = 100vh and I want to place a decorative object inside it so that the bottom half of it extends beyond the bottom of the browser window, but when I do so with absolute positioning, vertical scroll bars appear, allowing you to scroll to the bottom of the object. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried to set overflow-y: hidden to the container element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `overflow` property on the container object to clip the content and hide it without displaying scroll bars.

Here's an example of how you could use the `overflow` property:

```
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can learn more about this property from these sources:

[overflow - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

[CSS Layout - Overflow - W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

I hope this answers your question. If you have any other issues, feel free to ask! I will do my best to answer

Comment: Thank you. I had tried that, but I had the position:relative in the wrong place that was making it not work. I got it working now.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm glad you got your code working!

Answer (score -2):

To avoid the appearance of vertical scrollbars when using absolute positioning for a decorative object that extends beyond the bottom half of a container with a height of 100vh, you can make use of the CSS overflow property. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="decorative-object"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden; /* Hide the vertical 
scrollbars */
}

.decorative-object {
position: absolute;
bottom: -50%; /* Adjust this value as 
needed */
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 200%; /* Extend the height 
beyond the container */
background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Example 
background color */
}
```

In this example, the .container element has a position of relative and a height of 100vh. To prevent the vertical scrollbars from appearing, the overflow property is set to hidden, which hides any content that overflows beyond the container's boundaries.

The .decorative-object element is positioned absolutely within the container. By setting bottom: -50%, the bottom half of the decorative object extends beyond the bottom of the browser window. Adjust this value as needed to achieve the desired visual effect.

Additionally, the height of the .decorative-object element is set to 200%, allowing it to extend beyond the container's height and create the desired decorative effect.

With this approach, the vertical scrollbars should be hidden, and users won't be able to scroll to the bottom of the decorative object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we never know for sure why someone might have downvoted your answer, I have a feeling it's because it appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll continue to be a part of our community and contribute with your own, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.